# react loses 'this' context inside promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, axios

I am quite new with react and am probably making a silly mistake. I am trying to make an api call with axios that returns a promise.  When this promise resolves I would like to pass the result of this to a function that updates state on the parent through a callback.  However it appears that 'this' is gone as I get undefined. I guess as its resolved in the future there is no longer a 'this' context? I can get around it by assigning the callback to a temp and use that but it feels clumsy.  Here is the code:

```
axios.get(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    this.props.handler(response.data.thing)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

this works:

```
let handler = this.props.handler
axios.get(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    handler(response.data.word)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is where arrow functions come in. Arrow Functions basically maintain the `this` from above and don't override it within the function. You can read more on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Remember it is a newer feature so some older browsers won't support it.

The following code is an example using arrow functions based on your code in your question.

```
axios.get(url)
  .then((response) => {
    this.props.handler(response.data.thing)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

**Edit:**

The other way to do this without ES6 syntax is by setting a variable outside of the function. The other example you provided in your question will work even if arrow functions aren't supported. But you can also use the following code as well.

```
var self = this;
axios.get(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    self.props.handler(response.data.thing)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

This will let you access the correct `this` by using the variable created (`self`). Of course the downside to this as mentioned is it is slightly more clunky and not quite as clean as using an arrow function.

For more information about browser compatibility with Arrow Functions you can look at [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions). Although if you are using React there is a good chance you could be using Babel as a compiler which should take care of converting ES6 syntax and making it more browser compatible.

Comment: Yes!  Thanks.  Forgotten all about them.  New to es6 as well.

Comment: @user1584120 No problem! If you believe it helped you consider accepting the answer. Glad it helped tho!!

Comment: I will, you must have answered pretty fast as it won't let me accept for another 3 mins

Comment: @user1584120 haha awesome. Glad it helped! Happy coding!!